# Filtering Azure API Management Logs for Ingested Tracing in Dynatrace (2xx-4xx-5xx Response Code)

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing, dynatrace

I'm successfully collecting ingested traces from my Azure API Management (APIM) using Application Insights and OpenTelemetry (OTLP) integration with Dynatrace SaaS. However, I'm unable to filter the traces in Dynatrace whether they are responding with 2xx, 4xx or 5xx response code.

### Current Setup:

- APIM connected to Azure Functions backends.
- Application Insights integrated with APIM at 100% sampling rate.
- Diagnostic settings enabled in Application Insights to forward "AppRequest" and "AppDependency" logs to Azure EventHub.
- Custom OSS utility converts Application Insights logs to OTLP format and sends them to Dynatrace SaaS OLTP ingest endpoint. Github Project Link - https://github.com/dtPaTh/ApplicationInsightsExporter

### Screenshots

-> Ingested traces
[image]

-> Filtering by 4xx response code not returning any requests with 4xx error response code, though there are some requests with 4xx error resopnse code.
[image]

### Questions:

- Does Dynatrace offer any filtering capabilities based on HTTP response codes within the OTLP data received from Application Insights?
- If not, are there any alternative approaches or workaround solutions to achieve this filtering within Dynatrace?

### Current Setup:

- APIM connected to Azure Functions backends.
- Application Insights integrated with APIM at 100% sampling rate.
- Diagnostic settings enabled in Application Insights to forward "AppRequest" and "AppDependency" logs to Azure EventHub.
- Custom OSS utility converts Application Insights logs to OTLP format and sends them to Dynatrace SaaS OLTP ingest endpoint. Github Project Link - https://github.com/dtPaTh/ApplicationInsightsExporter

### Desired Outcome:

I want to filter the collected traces in Dynatrace to only include requests that resulted in 4xx or 5xx error codes for further analysis and troubleshooting.

Comment: Are you sure if Azure is not filtering it at their end?